# Connecting two Domain controller

Tags: cable

SIr/madam,

I am with learner license in networking 2008 window server,.what type of cable should i use to connect two domain controllers through a hub or a switch.

Thank you.

Comment: Roger that loud and clear.

Answer (score 1):

Straight-through cat5e or cat6 Ethernet cables. Use a switch for better performance (full duplex, no collisions).